# Vista says "system low on resources, please use an account that's already logged on" when none are logged on

Tags: windows-vista, login, resources

When I take my laptop out of sleep mode, sometimes it'll give me the message "system low on resources, please use an account that's already logged on". No accounts are logged on, so I'm forced to restart the computer. This only happens when the computer has been on for over 36 hours (asleep most of the time), but the computer has 6 gigabytes of ram and an Intel Core 2 Duo process, running vista home 64bit, so I don't see why it should be low on resources. Is there any way I can make it so I don't just need to restart the computer when I get this message?

thanks guys :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article might help: [Low On Resources](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistaperformance/thread/ec925cbc-51b1-4cfb-aff5-659be630606d).
It relates to funny situations that might happen if you close the lid too fast.

Other ideas that might apply in your case:

1. [Turn off Hybrid sleep](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-hybrid-sleep-mode/).
2. Look in your BIOS for the suspend ACPI options and try to switch modes among "S1 and S3", "S3" etc.

Note: Any of the above manipulations that doesn't help should be undone.